# What is a dedicated control/dedicated controller and dedicated attenuator?

Tags: word-meaning

The text tells about music modular synthesis and the above-mentioned words are the tools we use for the purpose of modular synthesis. Here is the paragraph:
So here I have a sound, and I can change the sound a bit. And again, don't worry about what's going on here too much, just like we did before, I can use another signal, control voltage, to change the sound for me. But nothing will happen because this signal is 100% attenuated and we can control this attenuation with the **dedicated control** for this specific parameter so basically, we can increase the range of modulation with the **dedicated attenuator**.

So an attenuator will reduce the strength of the signal and will give us more control over how much of the signal we want to let through. But there's another type of controller that allows us also to invert, to flip the signal and this is the attenuverter so let's send this modulation to the timbre this time. And already you can see that the **dedicated controller** for this parameter starts at the center.

Comment: " and the above-mentioned words are the tools we use for the purpose of modular synthesis." - seems like you've answered your own question, at least as far as ELL goes. Anything deeper than that belongs on either Music.SE or Electronics.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We speak of a dedicated device where it is tied specifically to one situation or purpose. For instance in your modern car there will be many microprocessors and sensors each dedicated to a specific task like deciding whether to turn on the lights, alerting you to loss of oil pressure and so on. By contrast the computer on which you typed your question is general purpose and not a dedicated device.